# Calculate the area of non-regular hexagon and trapezoid with the length of each size.

Tags: geometry

I am working on this problem.

A hexagon is inscribed in a circle. The length of five of its sides  is a, while the length of the six side is b.
My question is : a. How to find the area of this hexagon?
b. how to find the each of the diagonals's length?

What I have in mind is that, since only one side is different from all other sides, the figure is still symmetric. Then I can calculate the area of the two trapezoids. I think I should use the condition that it is inscribed in a circle. However, I am stuck with how to find the angles or what other fomula should be used here.
Then for the length of the diagonals, I am thinking that once I got the two trapezoids, I got them.

Anyway, I think I lack of the knowledge of some intermediate theorems. Thank you for the help in advance!

Comment: If you know the radius ($\space r\space $) of the circumscribing circle of the non-regular hexagon, you can express its area as, $$\Delta=\dfrac{5a}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}+\dfrac{b}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{b^2}{4}}.$$  Do you know the radius of the mentioned circle?

Comment: @YNK Hi, thanks for the reply. I do not know the radius. I am thinking if there is any analytical way to calculate the radius. of course, pure geometric way would be better.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Hexagon]

Instead of dividing the hexagon into two trapezoids as OP has suggested, let’s divide it into six isosceles triangle, five of which are congruent, to determine its area $\Delta_{{\large{\text{6gon}}}}$. All triangles have the center $\space O\space$ of the circumcircle of the hexagon (see the diagram) as their apices. The sides of the hexagon serve as the base of the triangles. So we have,
$$\Delta_{BOA}=\dfrac{a}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}\qquad\text{and}\qquad \Delta_{COB}=\dfrac{b}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{b^2}{4}}.$$

$${\large{\pmb{\therefore}}}\quad \Delta_{{\large{\text{6gon}}}}=\dfrac{5a}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{a^2}{4}}+\dfrac{b}{2}\sqrt{r^2-\dfrac{b^2}{4}}. \tag{1}$$

The equation (1) can be used to determine the area of the hexagon, if and only if we know the radius $r$ of its circumcircle. So, let’s derive an expression that gives us $r$ in terms of $a$ and $b$. Please note that $M$ and $N$ are the respective midpoints of the sides $EF$ and $BC$ of the hexagon. Therefore,
$$CN=ME+EP-PQ=ME+EP-DS.$$

When we express various lengths of the above equations in terms of $a$, $b$, and $\theta$, we get,
$$\dfrac{b}{2}=\dfrac{a}{2}+a\cos\left(\pi-2\theta\right)-a\cos\left(4\theta- \pi \right) \quad\rightarrow\quad b=a-2\cos\left(2\theta\right)+2\cos\left(4\theta\right).$$

We simplify this to obtain the following quadratic equation in $\cos\left(2\theta\right)$.
$$4a\cos^2\left(2\theta\right)-2a\cos\left(2\theta\right)-(a+b)=0$$

Since $2\theta\gt 90^o$, the valid root of this equation is,
$$\cos\left(2\theta\right)=\dfrac{a-\sqrt{5a^2+4ab}}{4a}. \tag{2}$$

Using (2) and the trigonometric relation $\cos\left(2\theta\right)=2\cos^2\left(\theta\right)-1$, we can determine the  value of $\cos\left(\theta\right)$. Since $\theta \lt 90^o$, we have,
$$\cos\left(\theta\right)=\sqrt{\dfrac{5a-\sqrt{5a^2+4ab }}{8a}}.\tag{3}$$

Considering the isosceles triangle $BOA$, we shall write,
$$r=\dfrac{a}{2\cos\left(\theta\right)}.\tag{4}$$

From (3) and (4) follows, that,
$$r=a\sqrt{\dfrac{5a+\sqrt{a\big(5a+4b\big)}}{2\big(5a-b\big)}},\quad\text{where}\enspace 5a\gt b. \tag{5}$$

When we substitute (5) in (1), we get the sought expression for the area of hexagon in question.

Comment: Thank you so much! and may I ask a question that what software you used to draw that geometry graph? Anyone knows this?

Comment: @Halk I use "Geogebra". Nowadays, a lot of students and teachers use it.